# Pandas update column with search string

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I am practicing with pandas and I am trying to figure out how to set the category field to Fees whenever there is a match of on "Fee".  I tried a masking technique that did not work.  Thanks

```
df = g1_2019[g1_2019['Description'].str.contains('Fee')]
df.head()

Index   Date    No. Description Category
495 3/18/2019   0   Withdrawal RW-ISA:Fee: International Service Fee    Not Categorized
496 3/18/2019   0   International Service Fee Assessed = $0.07 on ...   Not Categorized
650 4/17/2019   0   Withdrawal RW-ISA:Fee: International Service Fee    Not Categorized
651 4/17/2019   0   International Service Fee Assessed = $0.07 on ...   Not Categorized
879 5/17/2019   0   Withdrawal RW-ISA:Fee: International Service Fee    Not Categorized
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
mask = g1_2019['Description'].str.contains('Fee')
g1_2019.loc[mask, "Category"] = "Fees"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `np.where`

```py
import numpy as np
df["Description"] = np.where(df["Description"].str.contains("Fee"),
                             "Fees",
                             df["Description"])
```